# rollback nested transaction in java

Tags: java, mysql, transactions

We run junit tests to test our java codebase. Each test will read/write some data to a mysql database(possibly multiple tables). It seems that the tests are leaving behind data that is interfering with tests that run after it. Is it possible that we can abort/rollback all changes done by the test at the end of each unit test?

We are using cactus framework to test ejbs in glassfish application server. The ejbs can call code in the AS that can read/write to the DB.

We are using hibernate and jdbc to talk to the DB.

Comment: is your application a 3-tier application (controller, services and daos i.e.)? And what are you using to access database (hibernate, jpa, jdbc)?

Comment: How are you managing transactions? HibernateTransactionManager or Container JTA?

Comment: Mysql transaction process: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be **resetting the database** after each test with a simple **database script** you could run after each test, but this would **consume a LOT of time**.

If you are running integration tests, then you will be using real EJBs, there is not much you can do about this because it would be complicated to make them understand when the test begins and ends. For a simple operation you could force an Exception to cause a rollback, but if you use more than 1 transaction in a single test this won't work.